# Using text figures in itext

Tags: java, itext

How do I use text figures (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Text_figures) in iText instead of the normal numbers?

I opened my otf font in fontforge, and I can see the hanging letters encoded at 65538-65547 and then again at 65567-65576.

So the question is: How do I use these numbers from iText? Is there some kind of mapping/flag I can create so I always just get the hanging numbers, instead of the normal numbers?

I tried to do:

```
str=new StringBuilder("Number test");
    int val=65540; // The hanging version of the number 2 in the font.
    str.appendCodePoint(val);
```

and then adding str.toString() to a paragraph but that did not work(Only the text Number test were shown).

Comment: There's no flag. You'll have to replace normal number codes with your number codes.

Comment: I tried that in the included code. But it's not working. Should it be working like that?

Comment: Note that 65540 is larger then max char size. Is this a problem for iText?

Comment: You'll have to show the font.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem with the font is that the hanging numbers are outside the normal range for numbers. But I found a good solution:

I just opened the font in fontforge, and then I copied the hanging numbers, in over the existing non hanging numbers and then saved the font with a new name.

Now I can switch between the hanging and non-hanging numbers, just by selecting a different font. No need to change my strings just to get hanging numbers.